# How to restrict Google places API to country and only search by postal_code?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Problem: When you search in the main input the API returns all cities (also the bigger ones that doesn't have postal_codes). I want to make a search field that gives predictions mainly by returning postal_codes. Furthermore is google places API even the right api for the job?
Here is the demo code from Google where i have specified region and country

````html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Place Autocomplete Address Form</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
           * element that contains the map. */
        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }

        /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
    <style>
        #locationField,
        #controls {
            position: relative;
            width: 480px;
        }

        #autocomplete {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 99%;
        }

        .label {
            text-align: right;
            font-weight: bold;
            width: 100px;
            color: #303030;
        }

        #address {
            border: 1px solid #000090;
            background-color: #f0f0ff;
            width: 480px;
            padding-right: 2px;
        }

        #address td {
            font-size: 10pt;
        }

        .field {
            width: 99%;
        }

        .slimField {
            width: 80px;
        }

        .wideField {
            width: 200px;
        }

        #locationField {
            height: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 2px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="locationField">
        <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>
    </div>

    <table id="address">
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Street address</td>
            <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="street_number" disabled="true"></input></td>
            <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input class="field" id="route" disabled="true"></input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">City</td>
            <!-- Note: Selection of address components in this example is typical.
                 You may need to adjust it for the locations relevant to your app. See
                 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform
            -->
            <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="locality" disabled="true"></input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">State</td>
            <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true"></input></td>
            <td class="label">Zip code</td>
            <td class="wideField"><input class="field" id="postal_code" disabled="true"></input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Country</td>
            <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="country" disabled="true"></input></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
        // This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
        // of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

        // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
        // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
        // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

        var placeSearch, autocomplete;
        var componentForm = {
            street_number: 'short_name',
            route: 'long_name',
            locality: 'long_name',
            administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
            country: 'long_name',
            postal_code: 'short_name'
        };

        function initAutocomplete() {
            // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
            // location types.
            autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
                { types: ['(regions)'], componentRestrictions: { country: "dk" } });

            // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
            // fields in the form.
            autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
        }

        function fillInAddress() {
            // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

            for (var component in componentForm) {
                document.getElementById(component).value = '';
                document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
            }

            // Get each component of the address from the place details
            // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
            for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
                var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
                if (componentForm[addressType]) {
                    var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                    document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
                }
            }
        }

        // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
        // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
        function geolocate() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                    var geolocation = {
                        lat: position.coords.latitude,
                        lng: position.coords.longitude
                    };
                    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                        center: geolocation,
                        radius: position.coords.accuracy
                    });
                    autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete&components=regional:postal_code&sensor=false"
        async defer></script>
</body>

</html>```
````

Answer (score 2):

Use `componentRestrictions` ([docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete)) or simple `bounds`. `(regions)` type includes searching of a postal_code.

```
var options = {
   types: ['(regions)'],
   componentRestrictions: {country: "us"} // 2-letters code
};

var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputObject, options);
```

Comment: Well that's just an other way of writing the code i've posted

Comment: Google places is the only one that gives predictions. But be aware that searching only using a post code is way too ambiguous if you are seaching using an address and may not return to the results you intended. You have to be as specific as possible when using addresses.

Answer (score 0):

What we did is we created our own component as opposed to using the one provided by Google. Then we added ZIP code, state and city which we already knew to the search query (concatenated it to the end) for example 33139 Miami, FL that way our prediction/suggestion always includes it and limits results to those containing such information.